# How can I insert on SMS into inbox with operator name?

Tags: android, smsmanager

I want tosave operator Name also but i can't find any appropriate tag for that Any body please help me on This.

```
ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
values.put("address", originatingAddress);
values.put("body", sampleContent);
values.put("date", timeStamp);              
context.getContentResolver().insert(Uri.parse("content://sms/inbox"), values);
```

Comment: Operator name means??

Comment: @Segi I guess, he means mobile operator name(i.e mobile network provider).

Comment: yes how to invoke network name too in a SMS

Answer (score 0):

For getting operator name you can use:

```
TelephonyManager manager = (TelephonyManager)context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE));
String OperatorName = manager.getNetworkOperatorName();
```

and then use it in your code as you want OR like below:

```
ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
values.put("address", originatingAddress);
values.put("body", sampleContent);
values.put("date", timeStamp);     
values.put("body", OperatorName);         
context.getContentResolver().insert(Uri.parse("content://sms/inbox"), values);
```

Comment: Yes e.g;  abc(sms content) then date & time then operator / network Name